# Chatroom Emoticons PHP

Tags: php

Basically I have a chatroom and I was wondering how I would go about acomplishing this; Basically how this chatroom works is that the user types there message into the field and then it gets posted onto a html document and then the html document is then echoed out onto the chatroom and refreshed every 2 seconds My question is how would I make it so that `:wow` instead of coming out as just `:wow` would be posted as a picture instead? So that the chatroom is more engaging with pictures and emotions. has there been a previous post or something on this I just couldn't find anything that matched what I was looking for.

[image]

The chatroom is very simple here is the code for displaying the room;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#chathistory1").load('broadcast/uploads/<? echo $row['username'];?>/<? echo $row['username'];?>.html')
}, 2000);
});
</script>
<div id="chathistory1"></div>
```

The Form

```
 <form action="chat.php" target="my_iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"  OnSubmit="setTimeout('clearForm()', 200); return true">
 <div class="input-group">
 <input name="name" type="hidden" id="name" size="16" maxlength="32" value="<?php echo $usr['username']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="n" id="n" value="<?php echo $room ?>" />
  <input id="btn-input" type="text" name="message" autocomplete="off" id="message" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Type your message here..." />
   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat" onclick="testSubmit()">
                            Send</button></form>
```

Comment: Where is the code that displays the chat messages?

Comment: I have attached the code to how I load the chatroom what Im looking for in something that when a user posts `:wow` or something when it posts its to the.html document that it posts a `<img src` instead. I will also upload the post script too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're reading the content in PHP, you could use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$re = "/\:(wow)/";
$str = "OMG :wow have you seen this?";
$rep = "<img src='wowimg.gif'>";
$newstr = preg_replace($re, $rep, $str);

echo $newstr; //will output "OMG <img src='wowimg.gif'> have you seen this?"
```

Alternatively, in JavaScript using the [`replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var str = "OMG :wow have you seen this?";
var res = str.replace(":wow", "<img src='wowimg.gif'>");
console.log(res); //will output "OMG <img src='wowimg.gif'> have you seen this?"
```

---

In your code, I guess it's easier to do the latter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('broadcast/uploads/<? echo $row['username'];?>/<? echo $row['username'];?>.html', function(data) {
            var newdata = data.replace(/\:wow/g, "replacement!");
            $("#chathistory1").html(newdata);
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This is actually really handy to know thankyou for the answer; I will change how I'm displaying my chatroom and will use one of these two methods above. Thankyou really useful.

Comment: @LewisTyler I made an amendment, have another look at my answer!